# How can i use the items in a combobox as the source for an autocomplete function in a seperate textbox?

Tags: vb.net, combobox, autocomplete, textbox

Somewhat VB beginner here.
I have a list of items in a drop down style Combo box, but instead of using autocomplete on the combo box, i want to do it in a seperate text box, and use the combo box items as the source. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to setup the textbox properties. Set AutoCompleteMode to Suggest and AutocompleteSource must be set to CustomSource.

Then you have two options:

```
Dim items() As String = (From item As DataRowView In ComboBox1.Items Select Convert.ToString(item.Item(0))).ToArray
Dim items() As String = (From item As String In ComboBox1.Items Select item).ToArray
```

First line is the one to use if your combobox has a DataTable as source. 
The second line is if you have manually entered items into the Combobox Item List.

Then just add this line to make sure that you get the items into the list of available items for the textbox.

```
TextBox2.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(items)
```